# Main thread cannot get notify from thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm using retrofit2 to get data from web service, but when I called notify() from thread , main thread cannot get it . And hang app , I don't know why . I hope someone can help me .

`OnCreate()`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    synchronized (listRespones) {
    while (listRespones.size() < 2) {
        try {
            listRespones.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thread 1:

```
apiManager.getChannelListRespone(areaCode).enqueue(new Callback<CommonListRespone>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<CommonListRespone> call, final Response<CommonListRespone> response) {
        Thread channel1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (listRespones) {
                CommonListRespone commonChannel = response.body();

                listRespones.add(commonChannel);
                listRespones.notify();
            }
        }});
        channel1.start();


    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<CommonListRespone> call, Throwable t) {

    }});
```

Thread 2:

```
apiManager.getChannelListRespone(areaCode).enqueue(new Callback<CommonListRespone>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CommonListRespone> call, final Response<CommonListRespone> response) {
            Thread channel2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (listRespones) {
                        CommonListRespone commonChannel = response.body();

                        listRespones.add(commonChannel);
                        listRespones.notify();

                    }
                }
            });
            channel2.start();


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CommonListRespone> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: You should not wait for anything in `onCreate`! I suggest to use a [Loader](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

Comment: Thank you , I have try AsyncTask to wait notify and work fine ! .

Comment: Because it also executes asynchronously. As rule of thumb, in OnCreate, OnResume etc should not be long-lasting operations because they probably will cause "not responding app" errors. The Developer Site has pretty good Documentation on how to avoid this.